# Please help!! I get error when use ethers.js and move the code from jsx to tsx

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Jsx kode working fine

```
const handleContribute = async (fetchLaunchpadInfo) => {
    try {
      const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      const publicSaleContract = new web3.eth.Contract(PublicSale.abi, launchpadInfo.address);

      // Convert contribution amount from BNB to wei
      const contributionInWei = web3.utils.toWei(contributionAmount);

      await publicSaleContract.methods.contribute().send({
            from: accounts[0],
            value: contributionInWei,
        })
        .on('error', (error) => {
            console.error('Error contributing to the sale:', error.message);
        });


      fetchLaunchpadInfo();
      await fetchParticipantInfo();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error contributing to the sale:', error);
    }
  };
```

Tsx code (error code)

```
const handleContribute = async () => {
    try {
      const contributionInWei = ethers.utils.parseEther(contributionAmount);

      await publicSaleContract.contribute().send({
          from: signer,
          value: contributionInWei,
        });

      fetchLaunchpadInfo();
      await fetchParticipantInfo();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error contributing to the sale:', error);
    }
  };
```

error messege

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = execution reverted: Amount below min contribution", method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0xaED50be998EA3BDD02aAB20EeEB26071221e25Fe","to":"0x16D05B5FF23d78D7cF2E731c5d12c9dc13bF696E","data":"0xd7bb99ba","accessList":null}, error={"code":-32603,"message":"Internal JSON-RPC error.","data":{"code":-32000,"message":"rpc error: code = Unknown desc = execution reverted: Amount below min contribution","cause":null}}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.6.8)
```

Comment: Hi! The TS code as displayed is very different than the JS code - the JS code uses web3, initializes a provider and a contract, and then interacts. The function also has an argument. The TS code does none of this. From the error, I don't think this is the issue, but could you edit the TS code to include these parts too?

Comment: Thanks a lot mate